# Errror compiling smart contract using hardhat

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I am trying to compile this smart contract using hardhat and I am getting this error

> npx hardhat compile

```
contracts/FlashSwap.sol:7:1: ParserError: Source "node_modules/hardhat/console.sol" not 
found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "../node_modules/hardhat/console.sol";
^-------------------------------------------^
Error HH600: Compilation failed

The thing is I already have this in first line of my code and still getting the error
 

//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity >=0.6.6;

import "../node_modules/hardhat/console.sol";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add `node_modules` in the import statement.

Change the following line:

```js
import "../node_modules/hardhat/console.sol";
```

Into the following line:

```js
import "hardhat/console.sol";
```

Comment: Thanks even though import "hardhat/console.sol";  throws an error in VSCode. "Source "hardhat/console.sol" not found: File import callback not supported" it still compiled.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because the name entry in your package.json is "hardhat". Changing it to something else should fix the issue.